# Cannot build heob because windows.h cannot be opened

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use [heob](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-heob.html) ([source code](https://github.com/ssbssa/heob)), which is an open source program for detecting memory leaks in Qt Creator.

I've downloaded the source code and am trying to build the project using `build.bat`, a file they give to build the project.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> heob-ver.rc(2) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'.

I have the latest Windows 10 SDK and the proper paths in my environment variables. I'm pretty sure heob uses `rc.exe` to build the project. I also have the path to `rc.exe` in my `PATH` variable as well.

I originally thought it was a permissions thing, but I ran the command prompt as an administrator and it still did not build. From what I can gather, it can find windows.h but not open it.

Does anyone have experince with heob and can point me in the right direction? Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: _I can see windows.h in the location I have in my PATH variable._ this has no effect for me, the PATH is not used to search the included files

Comment: You're right, my mistake. It seems it has no problem finding it, but can't open it. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: for me `cannot open include file 'windows.h'` means _cannot find_

Comment: Since this software is endorsed by Qt and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same error, I assume there's nothing wrong with heob's code. Do you have enough information to guide me in the right direction (getting heob to "find" windows.h)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason heob could not find any files in the Windows SDK. I copied and pasted all of the necessary .h files from the Windows SDK directory into the heob directory (where build.bat is located) and the error went away. This is not the best solution, but it works for my purposes. If someone can tell me a better way, I'd love to hear about it!

**EDIT:**

The best way to do this was to run build.bat on the Visual Studio command prompt (VS 2015 x64 Native Tools command prompt, to be specific) instead of the Windows command prompt. I did not have to copy and paste anything.

After a little more research, it is because VS handles a lot of the dependencies that Windows does not. For some reason it seams build.bat's defaulting to the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to call build.bat from the Visual Studio command prompt, it expects that PATH/INCLUDE/LIB environment variables are already set for the compiler.